# como substituir um caractere no textbox, através da posição do cursor

Tags: c#

tenho um textbox com o seguinte valor "00:00".

Quero que quando o usuário digita um numero, o 0 será trocado por esse valor que o usuario digitou.

por exemplo:
se o meu cursor estiver no segundo 0 da esquerda pra direita e eu digitar 2, ficará assim: "02:00";

Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Matheus, posta seu código atual, você tentou fazer algo? se sim, posta para nós, assim podemos ajudar melhor você.